# i am unable to execute binary file in ubuntu. it gives error: bash, cant execute binary file

Tags: ubuntu, nasm, ld

$file as1
as1: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

$file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

how do i run the binary?

Code:

```
  SECTION .data
msg1 db "HELLO WORLD !!!",0ah   ;msg to be print
msg1len equ $-msg1
SECTION .bss

SECTION .text
GLOBAL _start
_start:
mov rax,1                       ;system read call
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,msg1
mov rdx,msg1len
syscall

mov eax,60          ;system end call
mov edi,0
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume as1 is your compiled assembley file. You seem to be running a 32-bit system according to the result of `file /bin/ls`. You can confirm you have an 32 bit kernel using `uname -m`. In that case it's impossible to run your program since you seem to be using the 64 bit registers `rax` ...

you can either setup a 64-bit system or rewrite your program to use only 32-stuff.